# What will be the number of solutions for the givem differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y''+(\sin(x^2))y' + ( \cos( x^3))y=0$ be a second order linear differential equation.

If $y(1)=0 ;y'(1)=0$, then what is the number Of solutions. 
 What is the fundamental theorem of existence and uniqueness theorem . using that how do we solve this.?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: The answer is 1 but how to solve it ?

Comment: You are in a place where the force is zero and your velocity is also zero. What motion can you expect?

Comment: I ll be at rest

Comment: @LutzL you mean $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is **force**?

Comment: It is an acceleration which in a physical interpretation is equal to a force. See Newton's laws, anything that changes the linear motion of constant velocity of an object has to be a force.

Comment: Can you please solve it using mathematical theorems .